# Jasmine test suite hangs in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, jasmine

My test suite has grown somewhat large, and now it hangs in chrome halfway through the run. It will "stick" around spec 86 and seemingly do nothing for a while.

Has anyone run into this? What's the solution?

Comment: have you considered separating your suits into multiple .html pages? (assuming you run your tests in a browser)

Comment: What happenes when you run them in other browser?

Comment: Are you sure that there is no loop cause the spec to hang. Our test suite has more then 200 specs and only need some seconds.

Comment: Firefox crashes, as does safari.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your memory. If you're leaking (like Sencha Touch does), you'll see this exact behavior.